# iPod Touch 4th Gen dock with AC or USB power and audio out?

Tags: ipod-touch, audio, power, iphone

I have scoured the internet looking for a dock that will allow me to charge an iPod Touch 4<sup>th</sup> Gen which includes a jack to connect it to an external stereo system.

I understand this can be accomplished with a standard USB charging cable (plugged into a USB-AC converter) and a male-to-male audio cable, but I'd like a classier way of docking the iPod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Apple Universal Dock](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC746LL/A) provides both a 30 pin connector for charging and/or syncing as well as a 3.5mm audio output jack.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect.  Not sure how I missed that.